# How to specify a Typescript function parameter array type

Tags: typescript

When I compile the following code (which to me seems incorrect because the type of the `const` and the type of the function `()` are different) no errors are produced:

```
export const yearsExtractor: (Period) => Year[] = (periods: Period[]): Year[] => periods && periods.length ? periods.map((period: Period) => period.year) : <Year[]>[];
```

When I compile the following code (which to me seems correct because the type of the `const` and the type of the function `()` match) an error is produced:

```
export const yearsExtractor: (Period[]) => Year[] = (periods: Period[]): Year[] => periods && periods.length ? periods.map((period: Period) => period.year) : <Year[]>[];
```

The difference being that the code that is not compiling is declaring the `const` as a function that accepts an array of `Period` objects (as opposed to a single `Period` object).

**error**

`(Period[]) =>`

**no error**

`(Period) =>`

Comment: You always have a mandatory name before the optimal type annotation. Therefore, Period is a parameter name at that position and the [] is invalid at that position...

Answer (score 3):

in the first instance:

```
(Period) => Year[]
```

reads as a function, with parameter `Period:any`, the second instance:

```
(Period[]) => Year[]...
```

is invalid syntax because you've not given a name to the function variable (you need to).

try `(period: Period[]) => Year[]...`

```
export const yearsExtractor: (period: Period[]) => Year[] = (periods: Period[]): Year[] => periods && periods.length ? periods.map((period: Period) => period.year) : <Year[]>[];
```